# number of "single-peak" permutations

Tags: combinatorics

> Write $0$ on a blackboard. Then write a permutation of $1,2,\dots,10$ to the right of $0$. How many of the resulting sequences will be *single-peaked*? (A peak is defined here as an element of the sequence that is greater than the immediate previous and next elements. Note that by this definition, the last element of the permutation (and the fixed first element $0$) can never be a peak.)

I've tried to encode sequences in the following way to distinguish single-peaked ones more easily: assign the letter $I$ to the $k$th ($k\ge1$) element if it is greater than the $k-1$th element, otherwise assign the letter $D$ to it. Then the single-peaked sequence must have one of these two formats:

$$I~\underbrace{D\dots}_{1\le}~~\underbrace{I\dots}_{0\le}$$ $$I~\underbrace{I\dots}_{0\le}~ID\underbrace{D\dots}_{0\le}$$

However, my progress stalled there because I couldn't find a way to count all possible cases given an acceptable encoding. Then I tried to count single-peaked permutations for $1,2$, $1,2,3$ and $1,2,3,4$ in order to observe a pattern or some recurrence relation, but again I could not find a satisfactory approach other than brute-forcing.

Comment: The permutation can look like I…ID…DI…I, but I don’t see this template in your two cases

Comment: I tried to attack the problem analytically, and failed.  Personally, I don't see any alternative to a computer assisted brute force.  I separately considered each of the *direct approach*, inclusion-exclusion, and recursion.  Each of these approaches seems like an analytical nightmare.

Comment: As an example of the difficulties in a direct approach, suppose that the peak occurs in position $~k~$, with the numbers $~A,B,C~$ where $~A,C < B.~$ It is true that the numbers prior to the $~A~$ must be strictly increasing, since the first element is $~0,~$ and that the numbers following the C are either strictly increasing, strictly decreasing, or contain a single *valley*.  However, the number of possible sequences preceding the $~A~$ is  affected by how many of the elements following the $~C~$ are less than $~A.$

Comment: Hint: if you compute some cases you can get [OEIS A000340](https://oeis.org/A000340), then there is a recurrence and a closed formula there. Then you can try to prove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @FabiusWiesner hint I was able to see how I can observe a pattern for constructing a recurrence relation. Let $a_4$ and $a_3$ denote the number of single peaked permutations for $n=3,4$. The $a_3 = 5$ as: $$0321$$ $$0312$$ $$0132$$ $$0231$$ $$0213$$ are all the desirable cases. Now the single-peaked permutations of $n=4$ have $3$ possibilities:

1. $4$ is placed anywhere other than last place in the unique increasing sequence, $0123$ : $3 = n$ cases
2. $4$ is placed in last element of previous $a_3$ cases: $5 = a_n$ cases
3. $4$ is placed either left or right hand side of the previous peak: $10 = 2\times a_n$ cases

So $a_4 = 3 + 3\times5 = 3+15 =18$. More generally, we have: $$a_0 = 1$$ $$a_{n-1} = n + 3a_{n-2}~~n\ge2$$ By utilizing methods for solving linear non-homogeneous recurrence relations,  we arrive that : $$a_{n-2} = \frac{1}{12}(3^{n+1}-6n-3)$$ For all $n\ge2$. So for $n=10$ we have $a_8= 14757$ single-peaked permutations.